# When is it acceptable to run app with no password on mysql?

Tags: mysql, security

It's not the crucial question, but I'm still wondering, when it's possible to have mysql connection settings to `some-user@localhost` with no-password.

1. It's potential risk in case of shared web-provider: other user can
   get access to your database (if they know `some-user` name).
2. Is it risky in case of VPS(VDS)?
3. If you run your own server with certain IP, I would assume this approach safe? Am I wrong? Could you mimic localhost IP from outside?

Comment: Why is it a problem to have a password for the user in the first place?

Comment: I set passwords even for test databases. I don't want my data wiped out just because I click in the wrong place.

Comment: @MajidFouladpour It's not a problem, as I said. But, for example, I may not be worried about mysql connection files being published in public repositories (when you send them to gitignore, you should remember that your repo won't start right afteer `git clone`).